# Using the Stripe API with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I want to use the Stripe API for adding customer data using plain javascript.

Unfortunately there are no Javascript examples in the Stripe Docs... https://stripe.com/docs/api

I want to use Ajax POSTS

**Now my questions are:**

a) Where do I have to put my api key?

b) How do I send data and where exactly do I have to input it into the script?

c) What parameters do I have to use?

Comment: Ask stripe support? They are very friendly :D

Comment: I'm confused; they show curl requests and Node--what other information do you need?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do any of this in Javascript client-side for security reasons. Most API requests require your Secret API key. This key is really sensitive and something you should keep secure at all time.

If you use that key client-side then anyone can look at the source of your page and then use that key to create new charges, refund all your charges or delete all your customers.

Client-side, you would only collect card details securely with [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). This gives you a card token `tok_XXXX` and then you send that token to your server where you will create a [Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

That last part can be done in Javascript using Stripe's Node.js [library](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#node) but the code has to run server-side.

Comment: @DavidJohnson I did answer your question. You can not do this at all. You have to do this server-side. And server-side using Node.js is fully documented in all the links I gave you. Client-side is not something you should ever do for security reasons.